# Use of unresolved identifier 'object' Xcode 6 Swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, ios8, xcode6

I am attempting to develop a parse based social network of sort, and am running into an issue trying to create a vote system for each "group". Within my TableViewController, using PFQueryTableViewController, I am receiving the error "Use of unresolved identifier 'object'". Here is the portion I am working on

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as GroupTableViewCell 


    group:PFObject = self.timelineData.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as PFObject
    cell.groupTextView.alpha = 0
    cell.timeStampLabel.alpha = 0
    cell.UserNameLabel.alpha = 0

    cell.groupTextView.text = group.objectForKey("content") as String

    var dataFormatter:NSDateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
    dataFormatter.dateFormat = "MM/DD/yyyy HH:mm"
    cell.timeStampLabel.text = dataFormatter.stringFromDate(group.createdAt)
    let score = object.valueForKey("count") as? Int
    cell.count.text = "\(score)"
    cell.groupTextView.text = object.valueForKey("content") as? String
    var findUser:PFQuery = PFUser.query()

    findUser.whereKey("objectId", equalTo: group.objectForKey("User").objectId)

    findUser.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
        (objects:[AnyObject]!, error:NSError!)->Void in
        if error == nil{

            let user:PFUser = (objects as NSArray).lastObject as PFUser
            cell.UserNameLabel.text = user.username

            UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, animations: {
                cell.groupTextView.alpha = 1
                cell.timeStampLabel.alpha = 1
                cell.UserNameLabel.alpha = 1
```

If anyone knows what the issue is here, please help out a beginner of a developer.

Adding another method from a comment for completeness and formatting:

```
override func objectAtIndexPath(indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> PFObject! {
    var object : PFObject? = nil
    if(indexPath.row < self.objects.count) {
        object = self.objects[indexPath.row] as? PFObject
    }
    return object
}
```

Comment: which line cause the error and where is the declaration of the `object` on that line?

Answer (score 0):

The line:
`let score = object.valueForKey("count") as? Int`

uses `object`, where is it declared and set?

It seems that `object` is declares ad set as a local variable in another method and thus is not known to the calling function.

Best guess is `object` should be declared a property of the class instance.

Comment: Before this statement, I have this                   `override func objectAtIndexPath(indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> PFObject! { var object : PFObject? = nil if(indexPath.row < self.objects.count){ object = self.objects[indexPath.row] as? PFObject } return object }`

Comment: That does not answer the question, `object` is a local variable to that function.

Answer (score 0):

There are two similar statements

```
cell.groupTextView.text = group.objectForKey("content") as String
```

And

```
cell.groupTextView.text = object.valueForKey("content") as? String
```

I believe the second one is where the error came from. Deleting it and it should be OK.